# Excel Macro event not working after saving data

Tags: excel, vba, function, events, activation

My macro function is :

```
Function IsColouredCell(Range As Range, Colour As Range) As Boolean
If Range.Interior.Color = Colour.Interior.Color Then IsColouredCell = True
End Function
```

And event code is:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
ActiveSheet.Calculate
End Sub
```

Use case: To check color match of target & reference cell.

Above code is active till the time i use it just after writing code in vba for n number of entries in excel. But as soon as i save the data on a already saved macro file. my event activation doesn't work and nothing happens on changing the color of a a cell.

Please provide the solution.

Answer (score 1):

1. You cannot declare a variable name `Range` in `Range As Range`. That is very confusing and might mess up the code. Never use reserved words as variable name. All names in VBA should at best be unique.
2. If this is used as UDF (user defined function) like a formula you probably need to make it volatile, because it only re-calculates on `ActiveSheet.Calculate` if any dependant value changed but not if a cells color changed:

So it should look something like below:

```
Function IsColouredCell(ByVal MyRange As Range, ByVal Colour As Range) As Boolean
    Application.Volatile
    If MyRange.Interior.Color = Colour.Interior.Color Then IsColouredCell = True
End Function
```

If you use that like `=IsColouredCell(A1,B1)` and it is not volatile the formula only re-calculates if the **value** of `A1` or `B1` changed. But it will not re-calculate if just their color changed, even not on `ActiveSheet.Calculate`.

Note that making a function volatile means that it is calculated **everytime** Excel needs to calculate something. So using volatile functions a lot makes your worksheet slower the more you use that function.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. It worked. But is there any method so that only when  I change color or data, excel recalculates, else it should not check calculation.

Comment: @AnkurBajaj No, there is no event that triggers when you change color. There is only an event if you change a value of a cell `Worksheet_Change()`. Note that this change event does not trigger if the value of a cell changes because of a formula it only triggers constant value changes (by either the user or VBA).